# Partial derivative of euclidean distance

Tags: derivatives, euclidean-geometry

Hello dear mathematicians,
I have two points in R3 between which I calculated the euclidean distance.  Now I want to find the partial derivative with respect to the first and the partial derivative with respect to the second point.
Can you help me and tell me, if this is possible, and if so, how does it work.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You take a partial derivative with respect to a one dimensional variable. It makes no sense to talk about a derivative with respect to a pont. You can talk about the partial derivative at a point, in a given direction. Is that what you mean?